# reducing a system of polynomial equations over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations, finite-fields

I am trying to reduce the system of equations 
\begin{gather}
xw^p-zy^p=1\\
x^pw-z^py=1\\
xz^p=x^pz\\
xw-yz=1.\\
\end{gather} over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. I want to reduce this system to the single equation $XY^p-X^pY=1$.

I tried and got nowhere. Can someone help?

Comment: Is $p$ prime? If so then Fermat's Little Theorem says $w^p=w$ for any $w\in \mathbb F_p$...

Comment: Moreover, it means $XY^p-X^pY=1$ cannot be true. It is false if $p$ is prime.

Comment: We are solving these equations over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: My previous comments are still true in the algebraic closure for elements taken from its subset $\mathbb F_p$.

Answer (score 1):

For example, with $p=2$ (but it works for all primes), there is a solution
$$
x=1,\; z=1,\;w=y+1
$$
with arbitrary $y\in \overline{\Bbb F_2}$.
This does not imply that $xy^p-x^py-1=0$ because we have
$$
xy^2-x^2y-1=y^2+y+1\neq 0.
$$